# BeautifulSoup question

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<parent1>
    <span>Text1</span>
</parnet1>
<parent2>
    <span>Text2</span>
</parnet2>
<parent3>
    <span>Text3</span>
</parnet3>
```

I'm parsing this with Python & BeautifulSoup. I have a variable **soupData** which stores pointer for need object. How can I get pointer for the **parent2**, for example, if I have the text **Text2**. So the problem is to filter span-tags by content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting the spelling on the end-tags:

```
[e for e in soup(recursive=False, text=False) if e.span.string == 'Text2']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do it in a single step. So:

```
for parenttag in soupData:
    if parenttag.span.string == "Text2":
        do_stuff(parenttag)
        break
```

It's possible to use a generator expression, but not much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Using python 2.7.6 and BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 I found Marcelo's answer to give an empty list. This worked for me, however:

```
[x.parent for x in bSoup.findAll('span') if x.text == 'Text2'][0]
```

Alternatively, for a ridiculously overengineered solution (to this particular problem at least, but maybe it would be useful if you'll be doing filtering on criteria too long to put in a reasonably easily understandable list expression) you could do:

```
def hasText(text):
    def hasTextFunc(x):
        return x.text == text
    return hasTextFunc
```

to create a function factory, then

```
hasTextText2 = hasText('Text2')

filter(hasTextText2,bSoup.findAll('span'))[0].parent
```

to get the reference to the parent tag that you were looking for