# Adding .onclick listeners in javascript loops

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I have a page getting JSON data via AJAX. I've managed to parse the data and create table rows from it. I'm now trying to add `.onclick` listeners to those rows using the following code:

```
function addResultsRows(tbody, jsonResults) {
    for (var i in jsonResults) {
        var tableRow = tbody.insertRow(0);
        var currRow = jsonResults[i];
        tableRow.onclick = (function () {
            window.location = '/otherscript?cusnum=' + currRow['cusnum'];
        });
        var currCell = tableRow.insertCell(0);
        currCell.innerHTML = currRow['cusnum'];
    }
}
```

etc.

The problem I'm running into is that ALL of the rows are ending up with listener functions that use the `currRow['cusnum']` value from the LAST row added to the table.

JavaScript isn't (and won't likely ever be) my forte - only doing this because there isn't anyone else to do front-end code. Is the problem something to do with using an anonymous function in a loop?

Comment: try this $(tableRow).click(function(){ myFunction(); }); if u want to do it with javascript then attach some value with your listener function as argument

Comment: Thankyou for your comment Alex but as I'm only spending as much time working on the javascript end of things as is needed (plenty of other projects I need to spend time on) I'm not really looking to dive into jQuery at the moment (although I know if I do end up doing much more with javascript I probably will look to using jQuery as an overall time saver). I'm assuming the $ notation implies jQuery

Comment: Not sure how I ever looked at that and didn't see it as a closure (which of course it is - function inside another referring to a variable existing in outer function's namespace) - especially since I [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430959/beautifulsoup-question/30180309#30180309)had just answered[/link] another question with code involving a closure (albeit a simpler one) hours ago. Goes to show what effect tight deadlines can have on perceptive programming :/ Thanks for showing me the obvious (and how to make the variable local to the function) @myTerminal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a change like

```
function addResultsRows(tbody, jsonResults) {
    for (var i in jsonResults) {
        (function (i) {
            var tableRow = tbody.insertRow(0);
            var currRow = jsonResults[i];
            tableRow.onclick = (function() { window.location = '/otherscript?cusnum=' + currRow['cusnum'] });
            var currCell = tableRow.insertCell(0);
            currCell.innerHTML = currRow['cusnum'];
        })(i);
    }
}
```

would work.

In your scripts, `i` retains the value from the last iteration in the loop and is the same for all the event handlers.

Comment: The problem is with variable `currRow` (`i` isn't used inside the click handler) but otherwise this is the correct explanation.

Comment: That does fix it, thankyou very much :) Just so I understand what is happening - the whole operation of adding a row is being turned into an anonymous function, and being autocalled on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @Juhana - One of the things I tried was changing the currRow reference inside the anonymous function to jsonResults[i] to rule any problems related to that out - sadly that didn't work

Comment: The value of `i` is captured and passed into the closure. In simple terms,  the inner `i` does not change when the `i` being iterated on changes.

Comment: Again, the closure fixes the problem because it turns `currRow` into a separate variable for each click handler. Passing `i` to the closure isn't even necessary. @Blair see the duplicate or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work for an explanation of what's happening.